# "ui.show" in Thread

Tags: python, pyqt

I was making feature nfc.

first, "nfc screen" is show.

Nfc the tag, "The screen hello" will be seen by the thread

"The screen start" will be seen by the next three seconds have elapsed, thread.

I think thread works well.

This code will show "hello screen" well, but will not show "start screen" well.

Why doesn't "start Ui" show up?

[print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqjAY.png)

```
class NFC(QtWidgets.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = uic.loadUi("/Users/kangbohyun/PycharmProjects/mr_qtqt/NFC.ui", self)
        self.ui.show()
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.Open_HELLO)
        t1.start()

    def Open_HELLO(self):
        print("thread1 start")
        res = self.serialtest()
        if res:
            self.mw_HELLO = HELLO()
            self.mw_HELLO.ui.label_4.setText(res)
            self.mw_HELLO.show()
            t2 = threading.Thread(target=self.Open_START)
            t2.start()

    def Open_START(self):
        print("thread2 start")
        time.sleep(3)
        print("3 second")
        self.mw_START = START()
        print("start window")
        self.mw_START.show()
        print("start window show")


    def serialtest(self):
        HOST = "192.168.0.10"
        PORT = 8203
        c = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
        c.connect((HOST, PORT))
        ser = serial.Serial(port="/dev/cu.usbserial-14120", baudrate=9600)

        if ser.readable():
            res = ser.readline()
            a = res.decode()[: len(res) - 2]
            c.send(a.encode())

            u = str(c.recv(8000),"utf-8")  # Wait for data
            print(u + "1")
            c.close()
            return u


class HELLO(QtWidgets.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = uic.loadUi("/Users/kangbohyun/PycharmProjects/mr_qtqt/HELLO.ui", self)
        self.ui.show()

class START(QtWidgets.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = uic.loadUi("/Users/kangbohyun/PycharmProjects/mr_qtqt/START.ui", self)
        self.ui.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw_NFC = NFC()
    mw_NFC.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Sorry, I have *absolutely no idea* what your question is.

Comment: I can't do ' START.ui.show ' after thread2(t2, i mean).

Comment: You really shouldn't create GUI elements and interact with them from any thread that is not the main one. Use signals from the threads that will take some time to react, and create slots to connect them to, in which you will eventually construct all dialogs and set their properties.